# Select a ListItem from DropDownList using a Linq Query

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, linq-to-objects

I' trying to use a Linq query to find and set the selected value in a drop down list control.

```
 Dim qry = From i In ddlOutcome.Items _
           Where i.Text.Contains(value)


 Dim selectedItem As ListItem = qry.First

 ddlOutcome.SelectedValue = selectedItem.Value
```

Even though the documentation says that the DropDownList.Items collection implements IEnumerable I get an error in the Where clause that Option Strict ON disallows late binding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, they were both helpful in leading me to a workable solution.  While I agree that using the methods of the drop list itself should be the way to go, I don't have an exact match on the text of the items in the list so I needed another way.

```
    Dim qry = From i In ddlOutcome.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)() _
              Where i.Text.Contains(value)

    qry.First().Selected = True
```

The linq query seems preferable to iterating through the list myself, and I learned something in the process.

Comment: I have reason to use FirstOrDefault in these situations to avoid downstream issues.  Check for null!

Comment: another answer for reference , it seems `Selected` is same meaning as `Checked` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Answer (score 9):

I can give you an answer in C#, and i hope it helps you.

The easiest way it to use the methods of DropDownlist, better than linq query:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 
       DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("2"));
```

If you want the linq query it would be like this:

```
var selected=from i in DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                     where ((ListItem)i).Text.Contains("2") select i;

DropDownList1.SelectedValue = selected.ToList()[0].Text;
```

Answer (score 7):

Anyone thought about:

```
foreach (ListItem li in drp.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Value == ""))
{
    li.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I was thinking of!

Answer (score 1):

My vb.net is shaky, (c# guy) but try:

```
Dim qry = From DirectCast(i, ListItem) In ddlOutcome.Items ...
```

I may have the DirectCast syntax wrong, but you know where I'm coming from. The problem is that at compile time, Items is not verifiable as as a collection of ListItem because IEnumerable's Current property returns Object. Items is not a generic collection.

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

simple way to select using  following code

```
foreach (ListItem i in DropDownList1.Items)
   {
      DropDownList1.SelectedValue = i.Value;
     if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text=="text of your DropDownList")
       {
         break;
       }
    }
```