# How to get values of selected items in CheckBoxList with foreach in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, foreach, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList like this:

```xml
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBLGold" runat="server" CssClass="cbl">
    <asp:ListItem Value="TGJU"> TG </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="GOLDOZ"> Gold </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="SILVEROZ"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="NERKH"> NE </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="TALA"> Tala </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="YARAN"> Sekeh </asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Now I want to get the value of the selected items from this CheckBoxList using foreach, and put the values into a list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523263/how-can-i-get-the-checkboxlist-selected-values-what-i-have-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Note that I prefer the code to be short.

```
List<ListItem> selected = CBLGold.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(li => li.Selected)
    .ToList();
```

or with a simple `foreach`:

```
List<ListItem> selected = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem item in CBLGold.Items)
    if (item.Selected) selected.Add(item);
```

If you just want the `ListItem.Value`:

```
List<string> selectedValues = CBLGold.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => li.Value)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: @نرخیاب: edited my answer to show how to select only the values. `var` is just a shortcut for `List<ListItem>`.

Comment: If you get an error that .Cast is not a method on the ListItemCollection, you'll need to add a reference: "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed plus to access on server side.
String.Join(";", selectedValues.ToArray())

Comment: To top up on this solution, to convert the values to list of int, just do this ".Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).Select(li => li.Value).Select(int.Parse).ToList()"

Answer (score 15):

```
foreach (ListItem item in CBLGold.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        string selectedValue = item.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Good afternoon, you could always use a little LINQ to get the selected list items and then do what you want with the results:

```
var selected = CBLGold.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
// work with selected...
```

Answer (score 2):

Following suit from the suggestions here, I added an extension method to return a list of the selected items using LINQ for any type that Inherits from [`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Every `ListControl` object has an [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of type [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  `ListItemCollection` exposes a collection of [`ListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), each of which have a `Selected` property.

#### C Sharp:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListControl checkBoxList)
{
    return from ListItem li in checkBoxList.Items where li.Selected select li;
}
```

#### Visual Basic:

```vb
<Extension()> _
Public Function GetSelectedItems(ByVal checkBoxList As ListControl) As IEnumerable(Of ListItem)
    Return From li As ListItem In checkBoxList.Items Where li.Selected
End Function
```

Then, just use like this in either language:

```
myCheckBoxList.GetSelectedItems()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> values =new list<string>();
foreach(ListItem Item in ChkList.Item)
{
    if(Item.Selected)
    values.Add(item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To top up on @Tim Schmelter, in which to get back the `List<int>` instead,

```
List<string> selectedValues = CBLGold.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
   .Where(li => li.Selected)
   .Select(li => li.Value)
   .Select(int.Parse)
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a databound `checklistbox` it does not work to get `item(j).Selected`, because the control does not have a selected attribute. If you clearSelections i.e. on Load, then apparently it now understands `item(j).selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to store the selected values in single column seperated by `,` then you can use below approach

```
string selectedItems = String.Join(",", CBLGold.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(r => r.Selected).Select(r => r.Value));
```

if you want to store Text not values then
Change the r.Value to r.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
string s= string.Empty

for (int i = 0; i < Chkboxlist.Items.Count; i++)

{

    if (Chkboxlist.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        s+= Chkboxlist.Items[i].Value + ";"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. You should explain your code a little. 2. Why are you posting an answer to a one year old question that already has an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my codebehind i created a checkboxlist from sql db in my Page_Load event and in my button_click event did all the get values from checkboxlist etc.

So when i checked some checkboxes and then clicked my button the first thing that happend was that my page_load event recreated the checkboxlist thus not having any boxes checked when it ran my get checkbox values... 
I've missed to add in the page_load event the if (!this.IsPostBack)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.IsPostBack)
   {
      // db query and create checkboxlist and other
      SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
      string query;
      try
      {
        query = "SELECT [name], [mail] FROM [users]";
        dbConn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, dbConn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
          checkboxlist1.DataSource = ds;
          checkboxlist1.DataTextField = "name";
          checkboxlist1.DataValueField = "mail";
          checkboxlist1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
          Response.Write("No Results found");
        }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          Response.Write("<br>" + ex);
       }
       finally
       {
          dbConn.Close();
       }
   }
}

protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string strChkBox = string.Empty;
   foreach (ListItem li in checkboxlist1.Value)
    {
      if (li.Selected == true)
       {
         strChkBox += li.Value + "; ";    
         // use only   strChkBox += li + ", ";   if you want the name of each checkbox checked rather then it's value.
       }
    }
   Response.Write(strChkBox);
 }
```

And the output was as expected, a semicolon separeted list for me to use in a mailsend function:

```
    bill@contoso.com; jeff@corp.inc; sam@dot.net
```

A long answer to a small problem. Please note that i'm far from an expert at this and know that there are better solutions then this but it might help out for some.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question; it's just a longwinded description of how you wrote a similar thing but it didn't work because you... didn't write it correctly.  Answers on Stack Overflow should be direct attempts to answer *the question that was asked* or *problem that was posed*; they're not the place to share similar anecdotes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this simple method to get the selected values and join them into a string

```
private string JoinCBLSelectedValues(CheckBoxList cbl, string separator = "")
{
    return string.Join(separator, cbl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).ToList());
}
```