# How to get value of selected checkboxlist items using javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project in which i have a checkboxlist which i have bound using

```
DataTable dt = new Process_Hotels().SelectAllFacilty();           
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)                                            
{                                                                 
    cblHotelFacility.DataSource = dt;                             
    cblHotelFacility.DataTextField = "Facility";                  
    cblHotelFacility.DataValueField = "ID";                       
    cblHotelFacility.DataBind();                                  

    foreach (ListItem li in cblHotelFacility.Items)               
    {                                                             
        li.Attributes.Add("JSvalue", li.Value);                   
    }                                                             
}
```

and now i want to get selected value ID of checkboxlist using javascript on button click.For that i have following javascript code on button click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                   

    function test() {                                                                                             
        var checkList1 = document.getElementById('<%= cblHotelFacility.ClientID %>');                             
        var checkBoxList1 = checkList1.getElementsByTagName("input");                                             
        var checkBoxSelectedItems1 = new Array();                                                                 

        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxList1.length; i++) {                                                          
            if (checkBoxList1[i].checked) {                                                                       
                checkBoxSelectedItems1.push(checkBoxList1[i].value);                                              
                //alert('checked:' + checkBoxSelectedItems1.push(checkBoxList1[i].getAttribute("JSvalue")).value);
                alert('checked - : ' + checkBoxList1[i].value)                                                    
            }                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                             
</script>
```

but the on clicking button the selected checkboxlist is showing 0. I want to get ID of  selected checkboxlist items.Please help.

Comment: how many elements are there in checkList1. i thing will only be one

Comment: there may be many elements checkList1 and if i select multiple items of checkboxlist then it shows multiple times alert message "on" instead of ID

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-selected-items-value-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function GetCheckBoxListValues(chkBoxID)
{
    var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= cblHotelFacility.ClientID %>');
    var options = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var listOfSpans = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        if(options[i].checked)
        {
            alert(listOfSpans[i].attributes["JSvalue"].value);
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

Comment: it is returning selected items text but i want its value

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxList1.length; i++) {
console.log(checkBoxList1[i])
            if (checkBoxList1[i].checked) {
                checkBoxSelectedItems1.push(checkBoxList1[i].value);
                //alert('checked:' + checkBoxSelectedItems1.push(checkBoxList1[i].getAttribute("JSvalue")).value);
                alert('checked - : ' + checkBoxList1[i].value)
            }
        }
```

Check to see id console.log() gives you any information about the object by pressing F12 on console window. Install firebug plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

May this code help you:

```
function CheckBoxCheckOrNot(jobskill) {
    var c = document.getElementById(jobskill).getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (c[i].checked) {
                alert('checkbox checked');
            }
            else {
                alert('checkbox unchecked');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note: `jobskill`  is a container id  which contain all check boxes.