# How to get checked value of HTML Input Checkbox in Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using a html input checkbox control in a modalpopup which runs a javascript function in the `onclick` event. Now my challenge is getting the value of the checked property of this control from code-behind to do some behavioral stuff. When I added the `runat="server"` property to it and wrote `chkIsPrivate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleCheckbox()");` in the page_load, the javascript function would not fire.

I have searched online for a solution but didn't get any. I'm hoping someone will help me out here.

Please note that without the `runat="server"` and the line of code in page_load, the javascript function fires when the checkbox control is clicked. But I need to get the value of the checked property in the code-behind.

HTML:

```
<tr>
      <td align="right">Private Campaign:</td>
      <td align="left">
             <input id="chkIsPrivate" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckbox()" />
      </td>
</tr>

<tr id="password_tr" style="display: none">
      <td align="right">Password:</td>
      <td align="left">
           <asp:TextBox  ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox><br />
      </td>
</tr>

<tr id="confirmPassword_tr" style="display: none">
      <td align="right">Confirm Password:</td>
      <td align="left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleCheckbox() {
                var checkBox = document.getElementById("chkIsPrivate");
                var pwd = document.getElementById("password_tr");
                var confirmPwd = document.getElementById("confirmPassword_tr");
                var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("privateHiddenInput");
                if (checkBox.checked) {
                    pwd.style.display = "table-row";
                    confirmPwd.style.display = "table-row"; 

                }
                else {
                    pwd.style.display = "none";
                    confirmPwd.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```

Comment: google is your best friend if used properly.. please show some more effort on your part and do a simple google search..come on now...!

Comment: trust me when I tell you that I've been googling for the past 3 hours on this issue but didn't find solution to my problem. It's really embarrassing. As you see in my post, I did a trial there but it just got my javascript function not working. Also tried `Request.Form["checkbox1"]` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I don't see any relevant code.. so @KaceyEzerioha sorry I can't agree with you in regards to when you say `As you can see in my post` please read / review how to ask a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: are you using master page?
the input name and id changes when you set runat=server
maybe when you call your input in javascript it doesn't recognize the Id
please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792290/input-name-and-id-changes-when-set-runat-server

Comment: Kindly find part of my code reflecting my challenge in the edited post. @Sam I discovered that in the course of googling but if I set the `runat="server"` the javascript function wouldn't fire. Definitely there has to be another way.

Comment: to read the input values in codebehind you needs to put the runat="server" attribute in the inputs.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha i don't see a problem with the solution of (Win) 
you could change your checkbox to asp:chackbox and in JavaScript call your checkbox using ClientID like this:
document.getElementById('<%= chkIsPrivate.ClientID %>')
it should work.
please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133519/how-to-get-value-of-selected-checkboxlist-items-using-javascript-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all of you guys for coming out to assist me. But I found a way around it to get it working.

What I did was to;

1. add a hiddenfield: `asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />`
2. create a property to retrieve and set the value of the hiddenfield
3. and added this to my javascript function to add `'true'` or `'false'` to the hidden field by saying this: `document.getElementById('<%=hdfIsPrivate.ClientID %>').value = 'true';` if the html input checkbox is checked.

This worked nicely as I was able to access the value of the hiddenfield from code behind and the javascript works when checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you want to retrieve checkbox's value in code behind, you want to use ASP.Net CheckBox Sever control *unless you have a valid reason not to use it*.

ASP.Net Server Controls are meant for that kind of purpose.

### Auto Postback when a checkbox is checked/unchecked

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="AutoPostbackCheckbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnCheckedChanged="AutoPostbackCheckbox_CheckedChanged" />

// Code Behind
protected void AutoPostbackCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool value = AutoPostbackCheckbox.Checked;
}
```

### Postback by button click

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox2" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" 
    runat="server" Text="Submit" />

// Code Behind
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool value = Checkbox2.Checked;
}
```

### Back to Original Question

I found few issues in your updated code. You can use server control.

Look at 5 <--- in the following code.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="IsPrivateCheckBox" runat="server" 
   onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)" /> <--- Pass this argument

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleCheckbox(checkBox) { <--- add checkBox parameter
        //var checkBox = document.getElementById("chkIsPrivate"); <-- Do not need it
        var pwd = document.getElementById("password_tr");
        var confirmPwd = document.getElementById("confirmPassword_tr");
        if (checkBox.checked) {
            pwd.style.display = "block"; <--- Make sure this is block
            confirmPwd.style.display = "block"; <--- Make sure this is block
        }
        else {
            pwd.style.display = "none";
            confirmPwd.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Win But I can't use checkbox server control because of the operation on the client I am doing with javascript. That's why I can't use the server control.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Win But the javascript didn't work after doing it exactly the way you recommeded. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did yo see any script error? You can download my tested code  [here](http://pastebin.com/rkeLnWCh). You want to create a new aspx page without master page and debug it.