# getting value of selected values of checkboxlist in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist

I have checkBoxList

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cheBoxTypeOfInc" runat="server" onchange="checkBoxchanged()"  CssClass="form-checkbox" Height="39px" Width="493px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="CommMotVehiAcci">Commercial Motor Vehicle Accident</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem Value="EmpInjry">Employee Injury </asp:ListItem>

                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and I am adding more Item to it as `addElement("InciRepo", "Incident Reporting");`
and defination of addElement is as below :

```
 function addElement(a, b) {

        var tableRef = document.getElementById('<%= cheBoxTypeOfInc.ClientID %>');
        var tableRow = tableRef.insertRow();

        var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell();

        var checkBoxRef = document.createElement('input');
        var labelRef = document.createElement('label');

        checkBoxRef.type = 'checkbox';
        checkBoxRef.id = a;

        labelRef.innerHTML = b;
        checkBoxRef.value = a;
        tableCell.appendChild(checkBoxRef);
        tableCell.appendChild(labelRef);

    }
```

I want to read the selected value  using Javascript as

```
function checkBoxchanged()
    {
        debugger;
        var chebox = document.getElementById('<%= cheBoxTypeOfInc.ClientID %>');
        var checkboxesChecked = [];
        // loop over them all
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
            }
        }
```

but its not giving me list. In fact when i am looking for the selected item its not showing checked also.
is i am missing something ? is there any other way to active this ? Please advice !!

Comment: Your element selector appears to be querying the wrong id. `document.getElementById('<%= cheBoxTypeOfInc.ClientID %>')` is not a valid element ID to select. I believe the correct one, based on your markup, is: `document.getElementById('cheBoxTypeOfInc')`

Comment: Furthermore after selecting the checkbox list, you'd want to iterate through it's children and get the ones with value selected. Here someone has done something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21133799/5330050

Answer (score 1):

this is how i solved it.

```
            var chebox = document.getElementById('<%= cheBoxTypeOfInc.ClientID %>');
        var options = chebox.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var listOfLabel = chebox.getElementsByTagName('Label');

        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].checked) {
                listOfLabel[i].textContent;
}}
```

Hope this help  !!

Comment: will `var chebox` be able to display any value if I were to run `console.log` after that statement? thanks