# Fill only selected checkbox items from checkboxlist into new list

Tags: asp-classic

How can i set all selected items from an Checkboxlist into a list? 
I tried this code but when i run it all checkbox items where added? I only want the selected items

```
List<string> WeeklyDays = (from l in CheckBoxListWeeklyDays.Items.Cast<ListItem>() select l.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks more like ASP.net than classic asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your snippet is C#/ASP.NET not vbscript/classic-asp
2. In your query add a WHERE statement to look at the "Selected" attribute of each ListItem, similar to:

List WeeklyDays = (from l in CheckBoxListWeeklyDays.Items.Cast() where l.Selected select l.Value).ToList();

Taken from: [How to get values of selected items in CheckBoxList with foreach in ASP.NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c)