# C# Populating CheckBoxList from database (strange column/header text name)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web, checkboxlist

I am working on small project ASP.NET Web forms, so backend language is C#, and I want to populate checkboxlist from database, and I did it, but values I get are very strange, I need to get names of database columns or something, because right now it looks like this:

[image]

On windows forms I would know what to do, (DISPLAY MEMBER = "Name") and problem solved, but on the web I dont know how to get columns name, because this looks so strange..

Thanks guys,

Cheers.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: You probably need to set the `DataValueField` and the `DataTextField` attributes of the CheckBoxList.

Comment: Yes @ConnorsFan, that was the answer, I was missing DataTextField, and by the way, how could I get id of selected value, I set also datavaluefield to ID from database :)) one more time thanks a lot dude :) Maybe CheckBoxList.SelectedValue ? :)

Comment: You can find some code to get the selected items in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c. You can then get the value for each item. (I don't think that `CheckBoxList.SelectedValue` is the proper way since several items can be selected.)

Comment: I used this block of code:     `List<ListItem> selected = checkBoxUloge.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
      .Where(li => li.Selected)
      .ToList();` and it works perfectly, could u take minute or two and explain to me/us why do the using Cast<ListItem> and why in general ListItem, thanks again dude

Comment: Overriding `ToString()` in your class would also do the trick.

Comment: I am not a LINQ expert but I think that the `Cast` is used to transform an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<ListItem>`, so that it can be queried with LINQ methods (see this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/querying-non-generic-collections-with-linq-to-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `CheckBoxList` is not instructed to do otherwise, it calls `object.ToString()` to populate the `Text` property of its `ListItems`. If `ToString()` is not overridden, the default implementation is `this.GetType().ToString()` which is what you are seeing. `GetType()` returns such a bizarre value because Entity Framework is dynamically subclassing your class at run-time.

My preferred way of doing this is to override `ToString()` to return the `Name` property, as it is [good practice in general](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) to override `ToString()` for your classes.

Another option is to assign the `DataTextField` property of the `CheckBoxList` to "Name".