# How to pass CheckBoxList values to another page using session in ASP.NET/VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

aspx page

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Veggie Cheese Burger </asp:ListItem>      
        <asp:ListItem>BBQ Chicken Burger </asp:ListItem>      
    </asp:CheckBoxList></h5>
```

I tried below code in aspx.vb file but didn't work. It just stores the first checked values. I am struggling to store multiple values

```
  Session("ptb") = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Comment: Store the values like this `Session.Add("ptb", CheckBoxList1.Items)` then retrieve them by casting that object (session) back out to a list item collection. Then you will have what you need. Also you are using selected item which is only one..