# How to get values of checkbox dynamically?

Tags: c#, checkboxlist, razor-pages

How can I get the checkbox values which are true from a dynamically generated list of checkboxes? My example contains three boxes, but I am using a Razor view to create many more. I tried basing my code off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c) SO post with no luck.

In my View:

```
            <CheckBoxList ID="cheesebox">
                <ListItem>1</ListItem>
                <ListItem>2</ListItem>
                <ListItem>3</ListItem>
            </CheckBoxList>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GCLanding(IFormCollection form)
    {
        var selectedValues = form["cheesebox"].ToString();
        return View("StringView", " & "+selectedValues);
    }
```

My goal is the get the checkbox value for whichever boxes are checked. For example a List containing 1,2,3 if all three boxes are checked.

Comment: Are you opposed to JavaScript form serialization of the input control?

Comment: No I suppose not, but I find it surprising there isnt a simple way to do this in pure c#..... the language seems overly complicated

Comment: You can have C# bind back with a model binder.

Comment: Thats a good point