# Making a Quiz using CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm a **Beginner**. I'm using a CheckBoxList for my Quiz. I want Values 1-4 to be the Correct answer and 5 to be Incorrect. Then have the results display **OnClick** through my **Results label**. Such that:

1. Fashion & Design Club (Correct)
2. Fishing Club (Correct)
3. Dance Club (Correct)
4. Art Club (Correct)
5. NONE (Incorrect)

No matter what, if 1-4 is included with 5 I want the answer to be Incorrect. **How do I do that?** I tried using an If statement I'm finding that this clearly isn't going to work.

My Code:

```
    protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {            
       if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            Results.Text += " <br> Question 4 is Correct. <br>";
        }
        else if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == "5")
        {
            Results.Text += " Question 4 is Incorrect. <br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Comment: @Kerith Paschall, check the answer that I just posted. You can set the label text in click event after the logic for answer being correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method to decide if 5 is selected or not. Call this method from your button on click event.

In logic below, if 5 is selected with or without others then answer is wrong, but if any of 1 to 4 is/are selected then answer is correct.

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    bool is1To4Selected =  false;
    for (int i=0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected  && CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value == "5")
      {
       is1To4Selected = false;
       break;
      } else if(CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected) 
      {
        is1To4Selected = true;
      }
   }

   if(is1To4Selected)
   {
     Results.Text += " <br> Question 4 is Correct. <br>";
   } else {
      Results.Text += " Question 4 is Incorrect. <br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Error: Since 'Project4.SubmitButton_Click(object, ImageClickEventArgs)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Beautiful. It works perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks that whether "NONE" is present in the list of checked Items then answer is `False`. If not then at least one of the other boxes should be checked in order for answer to be `true`

```cs
public bool isCorrect() {
    if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains("NONE")) {
        return false; //wrong answer is selected
    }
    else if (checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count > 0) {
        return true; //at least one correct answer is selected
    }
    else
    return false; //no option is selected
}
```